# Pointer definition in preprocessor directive

Tags: c

I was going through a programming manual for one of the microcontrollers I came across and it had the preprocessor definition as follows:

```
#define SCICTL1A (volatile unsigned int *)0x7051
```

and a statement in the source file as follows:

```
*SCICTL1A = 0X0003;
```

My question is, what is the pointer variable here and what is it pointing to, (I have never come across pointer definitions in preprocessor directives before since I am a beginner to C programming) and what does the assignment statement do?

Comment: The int at address `0x7051` will be assigned the value `0x0003`

Comment: In this case you have memory mapped I/O and the device is at address 0x7051. Then you are writing a command or something else to that address. That's all I can tell from the #define statement.

Comment: Note: Good programming practice would have employed enclosing `()` --> `define SCICTL1A ((volatile unsigned int *)0x7051)`.

Comment: That's completely unrelated to the preprocessor. Start understanding what the preprocessor actually does. The expression itself will become clear from every textbook.

Comment: @chux: … and using fixed-width types instead of standard integer types.

Comment: @toohonestforthissite True, Using  fixed width types is best for mapping hardware registers.  Aniruddh P Rao, are your aware  of `uint16_t` and family as in `#define SCICTL1A ((volatile uint16_t *)0x7051)` ?

Comment: @chux: I suppose that's some vendor-provided header. No beginner will ceate them theirselves.

Comment: uint16_t was defined in the header file which wasn't included in the question above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no variables here. The macro expands as text in place, so the 2nd excerpt becomes

```
*(volatile unsigned int *)0x7051 = 0X0003;
```

It casts the unsigned integer `0x7051` into a pointer to volatile unsigned integer, then references this in assignment. Essentially it stores `0x0003` into the `unsigned integer`-wide piece of memory that starts from address `0x7051` (or, however the integer-to-pointer conversion happens to work on your target platform)

`volatile` is required so that the compiler does not just optimize the assignment out - it must be strictly evaluated and considered a side effect (see [as-if rule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46455917/918959)).

As for the actual reason why this is done - it is probably some memory-mapped device, check the microcontroller datasheets for more information.

Comment: `volatile` is required when you want to tell the compiler to not optimize out memory access, in this case to a register in a memory-mapped peripheral. This memory will update without the compiler knowing it. Normally it would predict when it needs to access memory and avoid unnecessary memory access to speed up the code (optimization). In this case, those predictions would almost always be wrong and your code would not behave how you would expect it.

Comment: @bigwillydos: That's not correct. `volatile` does not enforce memory accesses.

Answer (score 0):

There is no variable there. Only the pointer.

the `*SCICTL1A = 0X0003;` is replaced by the preprocessor by the:

```
*(volatile unsigned int *)0x7051 = 0x0003;
```

You just write the location with the address of the 0x07051. That does it mean depends on your implementation

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using a TMS320F2803x Piccolo microcontroller: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/sprs584l/sprs584l.pdf

According to this document, address `0x7051` is Control Register 1 for the Serial Communications Interface (SCI) Module.

According to this document, https://www.swarthmore.edu/NatSci/echeeve1/Ref/embedRes/DL/28069TechRefManual_spruh18d.pdf, you're able to do the following with this register:

> SCICTL1 controls the receiver/transmitter enable, TXWAKE and SLEEP
>   functions, and the SCI software reset.